# Checkout uiComponent (input field) rendered multiple times: how do I apply viewmodel functionality to current input field only?

Tags: magento2, checkout, uicomponent, knockoutjs

Excuse me for the bad wording in the title.. It's a little hard to explain what I'm trying to accomplish in a few words.

I'm trying to add a custom field to the shipping address and billing address forms in the Magento 2.1.2 checkout with a custom uiComponent that applies its own bindings / listeners to that field. Below I'll try to explain what I already did (simplified):

I have added the field `myCustomField` to both the shipping and billing forms, using the following XML in `checkout_index_index.xml` for the shipping form:

```
<item name="myCustomField" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_MyModule/js/view/myCustomField</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_MyModule/form/myCustomField</item>
        <item name="id" xsi:type="string">myCustomField</item>
    </item>
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.myCustomField</item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">45</item>
</item>
```

For the billing form I have added the a similar configuration through a plugin/interceptor (`Vendor/MyModule/Block/Plugin/Checkout/LayoutProcessor/Plugin.php`):

```
public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject, $result){

    //Loop over all payment methods
    foreach($result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $paymentMethodForm) {

        //Get the payment method name (without -form)
        $paymentMethod = explode("-", $key)[0];


        if(array_key_exists("form-fields", $paymentMethodForm['children'])){

            if(!array_key_exists('myCustomField', $paymentMethodForm['children']['form-fields']['children'])){

                $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']['myCustomField'] = [
                    "component" => "Vendor_MyModule/js/view/myCustomField",
                    "config" => [
                        "customScope" => "billingAddress" . $paymentMethod,
                        "template" => "Vendor_MyModule/form/myCustomField",
                        "id" => "myCustomField_" . $key
                    ],
                    "dataScope" => "billingAddress" . $paymentMethod . ".myCustomField",
                    "provider" => "checkoutProvider",
                    "visible" => "true",
                    "sortOrder" => "45"
                ];
            }
        }

    }



    return $result;
}
```

This is what the `Vendor_MyModule/js/view/myCustomField` component / viewmodel looks like:

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'
    ],
    function(ko, $, Abstract) {
        'use strict';

        return Abstract.extend({

            myValue: ko.observable(),

            defaults: {
                listens: {
                    myValue: 'changed',
                }
            },

            initialize: function(){
                this._super();

                return this;
            },

            changed: function(value){
                console.log("Myvalue was changed!", value);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

And this is what the template looks like:

```
<div class="field" data-bind="visible: visible, attr: {'name': element.dataScope}, css: additionalClasses">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="myCustomField" data-bind="i18n: 'My custom field'"></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input-text myCustomField" id="myCustomField" type="text" name="myCustomField" data-bind="textInput: myValue" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

All this successfully renders an additional field in the shipping address form and (all of) the billing address forms. As you can see I have set up an observable variable `myValue: ko.observable()` and I'm using `data-bind="textInput: myValue"` on the input to bind `myValue` to the input field.  The `listens: {}` object in my viewmodel makes the `changed()` function execute whenever the `myValue` observable is changed.

However, when I change the value of the input field in any of the forms, it also gets updated in ALL of the other forms. With the above code in place, I get **47 console.log entries** saying 'Myvalue was changed!' any time I enter a character in the input field. I'm guessint this happens because the page contains multiple input fields that all bind to the `myValue` observable.

How do I make sure that the observable, listeners etc. are only called for the current input field I'm editing, and not for all occurrences of the input field anywhere on the page? In other words: how do I 'isolate' my viewmodel so it knows it should only apply its functionality to the input field being changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can directly listen for the specific field using the datascope you've defined in the XML `shippingAddress.myCustomField`

```
defaults: {
   listens: {
      '$.checkoutProvider:shippingAddress.myCustomField.myValue': 'changed',
   }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm afraid this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Yes, when I listen to the specific field throug the dataScope, the `changed` function is called only for that specific field, but still the value I enter into the field is automatically represented in all the occurrences of the `myCustomField` input field because the `myValue` observable is sort of 'global'. How can I make sure that the `myValue` observable is unique for every occurence of the input field?

Comment: OK, I think I just found out what the problem was: in stead of defining the observable 'myValue' through `myValue: ko.observable()` I had to define it with `this.observe('myValue');` in a `initObservable` function. Will update my question or add an answer for this later.